# Generate a nonuniform illumination (bias field) 2D image

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am creating a nonuniform illumination in MATLAB R2015. The nonuniform illumination (known as bias field) is defined as

> Nonuniform Illumination (intensity inhomogeneity) which manifests itself as slow intensity variations in the same class over the image domain.
>
> The non-linear degree of intensity inhomogeneity is indicated by the range of values of the bias field in the interval `[1 − α, 1 + α]` with `α > 0`

I used the below MATLAB code to generate the intensity inhomogeneity image in case of `α = 0.2`:

```
cols=256;rows=256;
alpha=0.2;
x = linspace(1-alpha,1+alpha,cols);
y = linspace(1-alpha,1+alpha,row2);
% Transform into a grid
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
bias=X;
imshow(bias,[])
```

[image]

However, I am confused about the term 'non-linear'. It means that the value in the range `[1 − α, 1 + α]` needs to be slowly changed in a non-linear manner. In the above code, it seems that it is linearly changing. Is this correct? Could you suggest me a method to create an image based on the definition?

This is an expected example which I need to obtain

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: So instead of `linspace` perhaps you want something like `x = (1:256)^2./256^2` , which you could then "stretch" to account for the $\alpha$ offsets.  "Nonlinear" could mean almost any function, not necessarily even monotonic.

Comment: Thank Carl Wittoft for your suggestion. Assume that I am considering in Medical Image Processing, as brain image. Do you know any common non-linear function for bias field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide an example for the generation of a nonuniform illumination using polynomials.

First, I take a vertical lineout (see first image) out of your last image, X being the pixel position and Y being the image intensity. For the horizontal direction I am using a simple parabola. Using kroneker product, the image is generated.

[image: lineout]

In order to ensure that the image intensity is between 1-alpha and 1+alpha, a streching is implemented as proposed by @Carl_Witthoft.

See code and resulting image below:

[image: generated image]

```
N=3; % degree of polynomial fit
alpha=0.2;

c = polyfit(X,Y,N);

y_f = zeros(size(Y));

for i=0:N
    y_f = y_f + c(N-i+1)*X.^i;
end

figure;
plot(X,Y, 'DisplayName', 'lineout'); hold on;
plot(X,y_f, 'DisplayName', 'fit'); legend show;

y_f = y_f./100;

xr = linspace(-4,4,150);
yr = 2-0.1*xr.^2;

img = kron(yr,y_f);

%% ensure that all values are between 1-\alpha and 1+\alpha

minV = min(img(:));
maxV = max(img(:));
mV = maxV-minV;

img = img-minV;                 % now from 0 to maxV-minV
img = img/(maxV-minV)*2*alpha;  % now from 0 to 2*alpha
img = img + 1-alpha;            % now from 1-alpha to 1+alpha

figure; imshow(img,[])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing code, In `c = polyfit(X,Y,N)`, how to achieve `X` and `Y`?

Answer (score 0):

An usual approach is to use two-dimensional polynomials of low degrees (lets say up to 5). For your images, probably a polynomial of 3rd degree would be sufficient to simulate/estimate the bias field.

If your images happen to have more structure (i.e. magnitude images), it is feasable to smooth them strongly (e.g. Gaussian blur with a large FWHM), since those field variations live on a larger scale than anatomical variations.

Comment: Could you show some MATLAB code example for that task?

Comment: No, I can't. However, it should be easy to formulate this as a linear least squares regression problem and solve it. Maybe you could have a look at https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/22868